# Solve system of 3 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$x+y+z=0$

$x^2+y^2+z^2=6ab$

$x^3+y^3+z^3=3(a^3+b^3)$

this is what i reasoned out so far;

$xyz=a^3+b^3$

$x^2+zx+z^2=3ab$

$y^2+zy+z^2=3ab$

$x^2+xy+y^2=3ab$

$y^2=3ab+zx$

$x^2=3ab+zy$

$z^2=3ab+xy$

I'd prefer a hint rather than a full answer - and how should I solve this kind of systems?

Comment: If you subtract the first equation from the second equation you also get $[3ab=-xy-xz-yz]$.

Comment: There is a standard way for 'solving' such things (reducing to a single univariate polynomial of degree 3): first use Newton's identities to transform it into equations of the type $x+y+z=\dots$, $xy+yz+zx=\dots$, $xyz=\dots$ and then you have  Vieta's formulas and you can write down a polynomial with $x$, $y$ and $z$ as its solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mechanical technique is offered by "Myself" in the comments. I'll sketch it.

Via [Newton's identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_power_sums_in_terms_of_elementary_symmetric_polynomials) we have

$$\begin{array}{ll} x^2+y^2+z^2 & =(x+y+z)^2-2(xy+yz+zx) \\ x^3+y^3+z^3 & =(x+y+z)^3-3(xy+yz+zx)(x+y+z)+3xyz \end{array}$$

(Read the background for information on how these can be obtained.)

Combining with the givens and [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we have

$$(t-x)(t-y)(t-z)=t^3-3abt-(a^3+b^3).$$

Thus, $x,y,z$ are the roots of this polynomial. If you want to go further and obtain explicit formulas, you can use [Cardano's method for the depressed cubic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method).

Answer (score 1):

If we set $z=-x-y$, then we obtain two equations in $x,y$, namely
\begin{align*}
3ab - x^2 - xy - y^2 & = 0,\\
a^3 + b^3 + x^2y + xy^2 & = 0.
\end{align*}
For $b\neq 0$ the first equation here gives $a=\frac{x^2+xy+y^2}{3b}$, so that the second equation becomes
$$
(3b^2 + 3bx + 3by + x^2 + xy + y^2)(3b^2 - 3bx + x^2 + xy + y^2)(3
b^2 - 3by + x^2 + xy + y^2)=0.
$$
Each factor is a quadratic equation, say , in $y$, which can be solved easily. Since there should not be a full answer, I suggest for you to consider the case $b=0$ (for $a=b=0$ we obtain $x=y=z=0$).

Comment: thanks - how should I solve $3b^2-3by+x^2+xy+y^2=0$ for example?

Comment: By the usual formula for quadratic equations, i.e., $y=(i\sqrt{3}(b+x)-x)/2$ or $y=$ etc. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Comment: yeah I see but it's not a binomial nor trinomial

Comment: It is: $y^2+(x-3b)y+(x^2+3b^2)=0$ is of the form $y^2+cy+d=0$.